# Update Gtk.Label dynamicall when time changes

Tags: gtk, glib, vala

I'm using this code to write the current time as a Gtk.Label in an app.

```
public bool update_time () {
        var now = new GLib.DateTime.now_local ();
        var settings = new GLib.Settings ("org.gnome.desktop.interface");
        var time_format = Granite.DateTime.get_default_time_format (settings.get_enum ("clock-format") == 1, false);

        time1_label = new Gtk.Label (now.format (time_format)) {
            halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER,
            valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER,
            margin_top = 5
        };
        time1_label.get_style_context ().add_class (Granite.STYLE_CLASS_H3_LABEL);
        time1_label.tooltip_text = time_format;
        time1_label.xalign = 0;

        return true;
    }
```

The time shows correctly, but I want the label to update to the latest time when it changes. How can I do that?

Maybe use `Timeout` in some way, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a Timeout, and in its callback change the text of `time1_label`. (Use `Gdk.threads_add_timeout()` to add the timeout callback in case any dependencies might be using deprecated GTK locking mechanisms.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Timeout as in this example:

```
public class RefreshLabel : Gtk.Application {
        
    private uint[] timeout_id;
    
    private Gtk.Label label;
    
    public RefreshLabel () {
        Object (
            application_id: "refreh.my.label",
            flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
        );
    }

    protected override void activate () {
        Gtk.ApplicationWindow window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow (this);
        window.set_default_size (100, 50);
        window.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
        window.set_border_width(10);        
        
        // create the timeout with your callback that update the label every 1 second
        timeout_id += Timeout.add_seconds_full (GLib.Priority.DEFAULT, 1, update_time);
        
        label = new Gtk.Label ("");
        var now = new GLib.DateTime.now_local ();
        label.set_markup ("<big>" + now.format ("%x %X") + "</big>");
        
        Gtk.Box vbox = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);
        vbox.pack_start (label, false, false, 0);

        window.add (vbox);
        window.show_all ();
    }

    protected override void shutdown () {
        // On close all instance of the timeout must be closed
        foreach (var id in timeout_id)
            GLib.Source.remove (id);
        base.shutdown ();
    }
    
    public bool update_time () {
        var now = new GLib.DateTime.now_local ();
        label.set_markup ("<big>" + now.format ("%x %X") + "</big>");
        return true;
    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        RefreshLabel app = new RefreshLabel ();
        return app.run (args);
    }
}
```